# How to make part of styles.css true, on given condition in react?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-flow

I want to make this part of code in styles.css true, only if toggleSwitch2 is true

```
/* if toggleswitch2 false then  */
.react-flow .react-flow__handle {
}

/* if toggleswitch2true then */
.react-flow .react-flow__handle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #784be8;
}
```

the problem is that the class that is being targeted by styles.css  doesn't exist as an element (for example div tag) inside jsx.

```
const [toggleSwitch2, setToggleSwitch2] = useState(false);

const handleToggleSwitch2 = () => {
  setToggleSwitch2(!toggleSwitch2);
};

<div className="toggle-switch-container2">
  <input id="toggle-switch2" type="checkbox" checked={ toggleSwitch2 } onChange={ handleToggleSwitch2 } />
  <label htmlFor="toggle-switch2">
    Make handles bigger
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: In css for conditional activation you can add/remove a class and use .myclassname syntax, or add/remove an attribute and use [myattribute] syntax

Answer (score 0):

Don't use conditional rendering in your CSS use it in your JSX code

```
const styling = toggleSwitch2 && {
    width: "30px",
    height: "14px",
    borderRadius: "3px",
    backgroundColor: "#784be8"
};

<input style={styling} 
    //rest of input code
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped whole jsx into

```
 <div className={toggleSwitch2 ? "enabled" : "disabled"}> </div>
```

and then in css i created this

```
/* Common styles for both true and false */
.react-flow .react-flow__handle {
  /* Common styles here */
}

/* Styles for when toggleSwitch2 is true */
.enabled .react-flow .react-flow__handle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #784be8;
}

/* Styles for when toggleSwitch2 is false */
.disabled .react-flow .react-flow__handle {
  /* Styles for false state here */
}
```

Now when const toggleSwitch2 is true then style of reactflow--handle will change, and change back to initial if it's false.